# munmap chunk invalid pointer (safeArray class)

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, safearray

I have a safearray class and I'm trying to get it to create an array of `Cat` types. When trying to initialize it, though, it gives me this error:

```
munmap chunk invalid pointer
```

I haven't found a lot of info on this error message and it doesn't tell me where it occurred so I'll post the entire file (it's not long)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

class Cat{
private:
  std::string breed;
  double age;
  bool friendly;

public:
  Cat(std::string b, double a, bool f);
  Cat();
  void setAge(int a);
  void setBreed(std::string b);
  void setFriendliness(bool f);
  int getAge();
  std::string getBreed();
  bool getFriendliness();
};

Cat::Cat() {age = 1; breed = "Siamese"; friendly = true; }
Cat::Cat(std::string b, double a, bool f) : breed(b), age(a), friendly(f) {}

int Cat::getAge(){ return age; }
std::string Cat::getBreed(){ return breed; }
bool Cat::getFriendliness(){ return friendly; }

void Cat::setAge(int a){ age = a; }
void Cat::setBreed(std::string b){ breed = b; }
void Cat::setFriendliness(bool f) { friendly = f; }

template<typename T>
class SA{
private:
  T* pT;
  int lIdx;
  int hIdx;
  const int dSize = 10;
  int aSize;

public:
  SA();
  SA(int n);
  SA(int l, int h);
  SA(const SA& arr);
  SA<T> &operator =(const SA& rhs);
  ~SA();
  T& operator [](int offset);
  T& operator [](int offset) const;
  int getSize() const;
  int getLower() const;
  int getHigher() const;
  template <typename U>
  friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream &os, const SA<U>& arr);
};

//Default constructor (size of 10)
template<typename T>
SA<T>::SA(){
  lIdx = 0;
  hIdx = 9;

  //Add one to high index so it's included as an index
  aSize = hIdx + 1;

  pT = new T[aSize];

  if (std::is_same<T, Cat>::value){
    for (int i = 0; i < aSize; i++){
      T cat;
      pT[i] = cat;
    }
  }
}

//Index from 0 to n
template<typename T>
SA<T>::SA(int n){

  lIdx = 0;
  hIdx = n;
  aSize = hIdx + 1;

  pT = new T[aSize];

  if (std::is_same<T, Cat>::value){
    for (int i = 0; i < aSize; i++){
      T cat;
      pT[i] = cat;
    }
  }
}

//Arbitrary indexes
template<typename T>
SA<T>::SA(int l, int h){

  lIdx = l;
  hIdx = h;

  //Slightly modified for arbitrary indexes
  aSize = (hIdx - lIdx) + 1;

  pT = new T[aSize];

  if (std::is_same<T, Cat>::value){
    for (int i = 0; i < aSize; i++){
      T cat;
      pT[i] = cat;
    }
  }
}

//Copy constructor (SA<T> arr2 = arr1)
template<typename T>
SA<T>::SA(const SA& arr){
  int s1 = arr.getSize();

  //Create a new array and assign it to the array pointer (pT)
  pT = new T[s1];
  int lower = arr.getLower();
  int higher = arr.getHigher();
  lIdx = lower; hIdx = higher;

  //Copy all the values in the array
  for (int i = 0; i < s1; i++){
    pT[i] = arr[i + lower];
  }

}

template<typename T>
SA<T>::~SA(){
  delete pT;
}

//Assignment operator (arr2 = arr1)
template<typename T>
SA<T> &SA<T>::operator =(const SA& arr){
  int s1 = getSize();
  int s2 = arr.getSize();
  int lower = getLower();
  int higher = getHigher();

  if (s2 != s1){
    throw "Array sizes not equal";
  }

  if (this == &arr){
    throw "Cannot self assign!";
  }

  //Same as in copy constructor
  for (int i = 0; i < s1; i++){
    pT[i] = arr[i + lower];
  }

  return *this;
}

template<typename T>
int SA<T>::getSize() const{
  return aSize;
}

template<typename T>
T& SA<T>::operator [](int offset){
  //Check that the index is between arbitrary index boundaries (or regular ones)
  if (offset < lIdx || offset > hIdx){
    std::cout << "invalid index: write" << std::endl;
  }

  return pT[offset - lIdx];
  }

//Overloaded version for reading-only
template<typename T>
T& SA<T>::operator [](int offset) const{
  if (offset < lIdx || offset > hIdx){
    std::cout << "invalid index: read" << std::endl;
  }

  return pT[offset - lIdx];
}

//Overloading std::out for printing
template<typename T>
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const SA<T>& arr) {
  for (int i = arr.getBase(); i < arr.getSize(); i++){
    os << arr.pT[i] << std::endl;
  }
  return os;
}

template<typename T>
int SA<T>::getLower() const{
  return lIdx;
}

template<typename T>
int SA<T>::getHigher() const{
  return hIdx;
}

int main(){
  SA<float> thing1;
  SA<float> thing2(0, 9);
  SA<float> thing3(15, 30);
  thing3[19] = 30;
  thing2[8] = 15;
  thing1[7] = 15;
  std::cout << thing3[19] << std::endl;
  std::cout << thing2[8] << std::endl;
  SA<float> thing4(thing3);
  std::cout << thing1[7] << std::endl;
  std::cout << thing4[19] << std::endl;
  SA<float> thing5(15, 30);
  thing5 = thing3;
  std::cout << thing5[19] << std::endl;

  //SA<Cat> catArray(0, 5); <--- ERROR OCCURS WHEN I UNCOMMENT THIS LINE
  //catArray[0].setAge(15);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Before we start looking as there a reason you are not using `std::vector::at()` ?  `SA<T>` could own a std::vector<T`>` and forward calls of `SA<T>::operator[]` to `std::vector::at()`

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of implementing a safearray class myself (it's a school assignment)

Comment: does replacing `delete pT` with `delete[] pT` solve this?